# Is this a Subgame-perfect Nash Equilibrium of the Two-round Rubinstein Ultimatum game

Tags: game-theory

Suppose a firm and a employee bargain over the distribution of $\pi$ units of money into $\omega$(the employee's wage) and $\pi - \omega$ (the firm's profit) in the following 2-round game:

1. The Firm proposes a distribution $(\omega, \pi - \omega)$. If the employee accepts the game ends and $\pi$ is distributed accordingly. If the employee rejects the offer
2. the firm proposes a distribution again. If the employee accepts the game ends and $\pi$ is distributed accordingly. If the employee rejects the second offer both sides get zero.

Both the firm and the employee have the same discounting factor $\delta$.

At the lecture yesterday my professor insisted that in all subgame-prefect Nash equilibria of this game the employee gets a wage $\omega = 0$. I attempted to object but he cut me off.

Let's represent by $s^F = (s_1^F, s_2^F)$ the firm's wage offers in periods 1 and 2 respectively and by $s^E = (s_1^E(s_1^F), s_2^E(s_2^F))$ the employee's response functions in both periods.

I think that the following strategy profile $(s^F,s^E)$ is a SPNE: $s^F = ((1-\delta)\pi, 0)$, $s^E = (s_1^E(s_1^F), s_2^E(s_2^F))$ with

$s_1^E(s_1^F) = \begin{cases}
    \mathit{accept} & \text{if $s_1^F \geq (1-\delta)\pi$}\\
    \mathit{reject} & \text{if $s_1^F < (1-\delta)\pi$}.
  \end{cases}$

$s_2^E(s_2^F) = \mathit{accept} \hspace{.2cm} \forall s_2^F \in [0, \pi].$

I found this using backward induction and the observation that a pay-off of $\pi$ in period two is worth only $\delta \times \pi$ to the firm in period 1. Therefore $(\omega, \pi - \omega) = (1-\delta)\pi, \delta \pi)$ after period one and  $(\omega, \pi - \omega) = (0, \pi)$ after period two give the firm the same utility. It certainly is a Nash equilibrium - there are no profitable unilateral deviations. But I don't see why it is not subgame-perfect.

Comment: Math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\text{\mathit{...}}`.

Comment: @joriki I dont quite get what you mean. I didn't use $$ to italicize text.

Comment: "accept" and "reject" are italicized within the math environment, and the spacing in "reject" is wrong.

Comment: After posting my answer, I realized that in the employee's strategy for the second period you excluded not only $0$ but also $\pi$ from the acceptance interval. Since that makes no sense, I'm now wondering whether you're perhaps using non-standard notation and meant that the acceptance interval is what would conventionally be written as $[0,\pi]$, including the boundaries?

Comment: @joriki "accept" and "reject"  are inside a mathematical expression. As far as spacing is concerned, it may be a browser issue. I opened it with both Firefox and Chrome and it looks OK. I would be happy to correct it if I saw what was the probem. Feel free to edit the post, of course.

Comment: @joriki it is $[0, \pi]$. Sorry, my fault. Please undelete your answer.

Comment: I'll try to post a proper answer, but it makes little sense to undelete this one, since it was based on my understanding that $0$ was excluded.

Comment: OK, I made the change. I'm also using Firefox, I don't think it's a browser thing. You should be able to see the difference here:

$$
reject\\\mathit{reject}
$$

(The `\text` command in my first comment was wrong; it's just `\mathit{...}`.)

Comment: I adapted my answer to the edited question and undeleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strategy profile is not a subgame-perfect Nash equilibrium because the employee’s threat to reject an offer less than $(1-\delta)\pi$ in the first period is not credible. The employee knows that she will get $0$ if she follows through on this threat, and thus profits by deviating unilaterally and accepting a lower offer. A subgame-perfect Nash equilibrium must be a Nash equilibrium for all subgames, including the branches that would not actually be taken in applying the strategy profile. Otherwise the concept wouldn’t serve the purpose of eliminating non-credible threats.